# Error in calculating pps for h264 rtp stream

Tags: c, gstreamer, h.264, rtp

I have a problem in my Gstreamer pipeline that causes the sprop-parameter-sets to (i think) overflow its buffer. I am doing this in a iMX6 board and my pipeline is `appsrc format=3 ! imxvpuenc_h264 ! rtph264pay` and I use an RTSP server for accessing the pipeline. The pipeline works if a static image is sent, but in the case of a video it stops working by calculating the wrong pps.

I have tried using a static sprop-parameter-sets for rtph264pay by setting its property, but in this case the same thing happens in rtph264depay that calculates a new sprop-parameter-set. The output from the caps creation can be seen below:

> 0:01:15.970217009   578 0xa482ad50 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:809:gst_event_new_caps: creating caps event application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, packetization-mode=(string)1, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)"Z0JAIKaAUAIGQAA\=\,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...

and this continues on for about a hundred or more lines and the device crashes if the pipeline isn't stopped. This should have only a few more characters after the first comma. Can someone tell why this would happen and provide a solution?